# Android kotlin Arraylist of objects get specific value

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I have ArrayList and i want to get him some specific object values and insert them to another ArrayList, but I can't get the specific values

```
val listA = ArrayList<User>()
```

this list contains some users with their **id,name, and email** so i need to get all user's whose names are **john** and **id,email** will be any value

Comment: `listA.filter { it.name == "john" }`

Comment: Thank you, please post it as an answer to help the others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `filter` function i.e

```
listA.filter { it.name == "john" }
```

or use `groupBy` with `forEach` i.e

```
listA.groupBy{ it.name }.forEach{name, list ->

//name: the key for each list according to their names
//list: a grouped list according to the names

}
```

Comment: Thank you, the groupBy is saves me, the second solution